# Plot theoretical Binomial distribution with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, python

I am trying to plot the theoretical binomial distribution with `pgfplots` but don't get the desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}


\begin{python}%
import numpy as np
from scipy import special
N,p=150,.5
def f(n):
    return special.binom(N,n)*p**n*(1-p)**(N-n)
s = map(f,range(1,N))
np.savetxt("bernoulli.dat",s,fmt='%0.5f')
\end{python}%


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[]
    \addplot[%
    hist={density,bins=150,data min=0,data max=150},
    fill=green,
    ]%
    table [y index=0] {bernoulli.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Any idea what's wrong with this?

**Edit**

You have to compile this one with `pdflatex` and `--shell-escape`.

`bernoulli.dat` looks like this:

```
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00001
0.00001
0.00003
0.00005
0.00010
0.00017
0.00031
0.00052
0.00085
0.00137
0.00213
0.00324
0.00478
0.00686
0.00958
0.01302
0.01723
0.02219
0.02782
0.03396
0.04035
0.04669
0.05261
0.05773
0.06168
0.06418
0.06504
0.06418
0.06168
0.05773
0.05261
0.04669
0.04035
0.03396
0.02782
0.02219
0.01723
0.01302
0.00958
0.00686
0.00478
0.00324
0.00213
0.00137
0.00085
0.00052
0.00031
0.00017
0.00010
0.00005
0.00003
0.00001
0.00001
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
```

Comment: If bernoulli.dat has the right contents then this is a tikz/pgfplots question that someone (not me) should be able to answer here. Perhaps add the contents of bernoulli.dat to your question.

Comment: I've always put both x and y (comma delimited) into a file to be read by table.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I just tried your suggestion by replacing `s = map(f,range(1,N))` by `s = zip(range(1,N),map(f,range(1,N)))` I get a list ouf tuples then I have to remove the `[y index=0]` part. However I get the same result. If I plot it without `hist` option I the desired curve but I need it as histogram.

Comment: @Anna I don't think that you want the `hist` option: you already have the distribution. I think you rather need something like `const plot`.

Comment: @cgnieder `const plot` works, but I want also the vertical lines as in a histogram, i.e. it should look exactly like a histogram.

Comment: @Anna `ybar` then?

Answer (score 3):

Putting @John Kormylos und @cgnieders comments together I get the following solution using `ybar interval` instead of `hist`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}


\begin{python}%
import numpy as np
from scipy import special
N,p=150,.5
def f(n):
    return special.binom(N,n)*p**n*(1-p)**(N-n)
s = zip(range(1,N),map(f,range(1,N)))
np.savetxt("bernoulli.dat",s,fmt='%0.5f')
\end{python}%


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=10cm]
    \addplot[%
    ybar interval,
    fill=blue!30,
    draw opacity=0.5,
    line width=0.4pt,
    ]%
    table {bernoulli.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output: [image: output]

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by Anna but you might be interested in knowing you can get the same results using `sagetex` package without the need for creating the data file along the way. Sage gives you Python plus extra commands helpful for math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
p = .5
N = 140

output =""
output += r"\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]"
output += r"\begin{axis}[width=10cm]"
output += r"\addplot[ybar interval,fill=blue!30,draw opacity=0.5,line   width=0.4pt] coordinates{"
for i in range(0,N):
    output += r"(%d, %f) "%(i, binomial(N,i)*p^i*(1-p)^(N-i))

output += r"};"
output += r"\end{axis}"
output += r"\end{tikzpicture}"
\end{sagesilent}
\sagestr{output}
\end{document}
```

No data file needed to get this output running in [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/):
[image]